# How to delete a post-build action in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I cannot figure out how to remove/delete Post Build Actions from Jenkins.  Can anyone tell me how to remove post-build actions via the Jenkins web interface?

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Open Firefox and browse to the Jenkins web interface
2. Click on the hyperlink for the job I'm interested in
3. Click the "Configure" hyperlink in the left-hand navbar
4. Find the post-build action that I want to delete

If I click-and-hold on the post-build action I can move it around and re-order it but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to delete it.  I've tried dragging it off the screen, pressing delete, and right-clicking but none of these actions removed it.

Thank you for any help in advance.  Below is a screenshot, in case it will provide some context.

[image]

Comment: If you scroll to the right, do you find a "Delete" button for the step?

Comment: I do _not_ see a "Delete" button if I scroll to the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick test it seems that there should be a delete button there.

[image: Screenshot of Jenkins IRC configuration]

I'm not sure why it is not there on your installation but I have seen that behavior before with different configurations on my own Jenkins installation. The only way I know to get rid of the configuration section is to remove it from the job configuration file. For that you'll need write access to the Jenkins directory on your build server.

First locate the configuration file of the job from which you want to remove the IRC section, it will be in the Jenkins directory under jobs, e.g. if your job is called 'my awesome job' then you'll find it in

```
<JENKINS_PATH>\jobs\my awesome job\config.xml
```

where `<JENKINS_PATH>` is the path to your Jenkins installation. When you open that configuration file you'll see something like this (note that this config is abbreviated, yours will probably be much bigger):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>My description</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm" plugin="tfs@1.20">
    <!-- SCM stuff lives here -->
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <!-- Your builders config lives here -->
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.ircbot.IrcPublisher plugin="ircbot@2.22">
      <targets class="empty-list"/>
      <strategy>ALL</strategy>
      <notifyOnBuildStart>false</notifyOnBuildStart>
      <notifySuspects>false</notifySuspects>
      <notifyCulprits>false</notifyCulprits>
      <notifyFixers>false</notifyFixers>
      <notifyUpstreamCommitters>false</notifyUpstreamCommitters>
      <buildToChatNotifier class="hudson.plugins.im.build_notify.DefaultBuildToChatNotifier" plugin="instant-messaging@1.25"/>
      <matrixMultiplier>ONLY_CONFIGURATIONS</matrixMultiplier>
      <channels/>
    </hudson.plugins.ircbot.IrcPublisher>
  </publishers>
</project>
```

Find the `publishers` section and inside that the `hudson.plugins.ircbot.IrcPublisher` section. Then comment out the IRC section.

After you do that save the configuration file and go back into Jenkins. Go to 'Manage Jenkins' and from there reload the configuration. Once that is done your rogue configuration should be gone.

[image: Reload Jenkins configuration]

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me.  Thank you for taking the time to put this together.  I'm still not sure _why_ the delete button is not present, but I'm not too worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a delete button just below each job.

Either your browser is blocking this from appearing, or there is a problem with your Jenkins server.

- What version of Jenkins is your server? (Shown on the bottom right of each page).
- Does the button appear with IE or chrome?

[image: An example of where the delete button should be]

Comment: I am using Jenkins 1.480.3 running on Windows 7 32-bit.  I only recall testing in Firefox; I don't think I tried Chrome or IE.  Thank you for offering to help; I was able to fix the issue by editing the job's xml, as mentioned in a separate response.

Answer (score 0):

My belief is that the presence or absence of a delete button on a given post-build action depends on whether the plugin authors decided to put one there or not.  The standard post-build actions all have delete buttons, but certain additional ones I have installed do not, and it's definitely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the xunit plugin?

See this bug in the bugtracker

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17193